# Insert current branch name in insert mode in Neovim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I'd like to create a hotkey to insert the current branch name directly in insert mode with the hotkey `<C-b>`. I use the plugin gitsigns which has a variable `vim.b.gitsigns_head` containing the current branch but I can't seem to find a way to input it. I figured I need to add something like

```
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-b>', vim.b.gitsigns_head)
```

but I can't find any way to reference and print the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-b>', 'b:gitsigns_head', {expr = true})
```

Or if you prefer a "pure" lua version:

```lua
lua vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-b>', "luaeval('vim.b.gitsigns_head')", {expr = true})
```

The `{expr = true}` makes that the lhs is evaluated instead of used directly as input.